# Can anyone tell me why I get an error in Java while using SSL?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, applet

I have been trying to get a connection between a Cpp server and a Java applet client but when I run the applet I get this error in the browser.  I have the certificate in the trust store file (let me know if I don't need it).  Any help would be appreciated.

> access denied ("java.util.propertypermission"
>   "javax.net.ssl.truststore" "write")

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class no2 extends Applet {

   int width, height;

   public void init() {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystore.jks"); 
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit"); 

        String trustStore = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore"); 
        if (trustStore == null) { 
            System.out.println("javax.net.ssl.trustStore is not defined"); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("javax.net.ssl.trustStore = " + trustStore); 
        } 

        try {

        PrintWriter toServer = null;
        BufferedReader fromServer = null;

        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("192.168.0.10", 12120);

        String[] newProtocols = {"TLSv1"};
        sslsocket.setEnabledProtocols(newProtocols);

        toServer = new PrintWriter(sslsocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        toServer.println("Data1\n");
        toServer.println("Data2\n");

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream());
        fromServer = new BufferedReader(isr, 1);

        } catch (Exception exception) {

            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: There are bigger problems down the track. Why are you setting the truststore to a keystore? And where is the keystore.jks file supposed to be coming from? At the moment you are assuming the user has one in his current working directory when he executes the browser. How is that going to come about?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set system properties within an Applet. You can't access local file (keystore.jks) systems either (unless you request for a specific permission to do so).

You can pass special parameters to JVM like stated in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html) like this:

```
<APPLET archive="my_applet.jar" code="MyApplet" width="300" height="300">
    <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=keystore.jks">
</APPLET>
```

But again, take care of the special permissions you'd need to access local files.

Comment: If you could help me further... The data is still not being sent to the server

Comment: Should I start a new question for getting the data (data1, data2) from the client to the server